# How can I debug both rust and C in the same project in vscode?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, debugging, rust

I'm writing a wrapper library around libvmaf in rust and I was able to successfully write a _sys crate for the library which can both link to a libvmaf dynamic library as well as building libvmaf from source

As I was writing an example for a different project that uses this _sys library I got an access violation. I wanted to debug what was going on in the libvmaf source files to see what I could be doing wrong with my pointers.

Here's an example of the assembly I see in the debugger

```
7FF65C518D43: 48 8D 15 F6 6E 27 00       leaq   0x276ef6(%rip), %rdx  ; built_in_models
7FF65C518D4A: 48 01 D0                   addq   %rdx, %rax
7FF65C518D4D: 48 89 45 F8                movq   %rax, -0x8(%rbp)
7FF65C518D51: EB 0A                      jmp    0x7ff65c518d5d  ; <+125> at 106:8
7FF65C518D53: 83 45 F4 01                addl   $0x1, -0xc(%rbp)
7FF65C518D57: 83 7D F4 03                cmpl   $0x3, -0xc(%rbp)
7FF65C518D5B: 76 A8                      jbe    0x7ff65c518d05  ; <+37> at 100:48
7FF65C518D5D: 48 83 7D F8 00             cmpq   $0x0, -0x8(%rbp)
7FF65C518D62: 75 22                      jne    0x7ff65c518d86  ; <+166> at 113:60
7FF65C518D64: 48 8B 45 20                movq   0x20(%rbp), %rax
7FF65C518D68: 49 89 C0                   movq   %rax, %r8
7FF65C518D6B: 48 8D 05 46 6F 27 00       leaq   0x276f46(%rip), %rax  ; built_in_models + 120
```

the fact I get function names and line numbers is a good sign that I'm linking to the library I built from source, yet the vscode debugger seems to not be able to display the source files?

I'm using the `CodeLLDB` plugin as my debugger

here's the relevant portion of my `launch.json`

```json
 {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug example 'get_vmaf_scores'",
            "cargo": {
                "args": [
                    "build",
                    "--example=get_vmaf_scores",
                    "--package=libvmaf-rs",
                    "--features",
                    "libvmaf-sys/build,libvmaf-sys/static"
                ],
                "filter": {
                    "name": "get_vmaf_scores",
                    "kind": "example"
                }
            },
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
```

also i'm pretty sure i'm packaging the source files correctly as well

here's the relevant portion of the Cargo.toml for my _sys crate

```ini
[package]
name = "libvmaf-sys"
version = "0.4.2"
edition = "2021"
description = "Library bindings for Netflix's VMAF"
license = "GPL-3.0-or-later"
repository = "https://github.com/ThatNerdUKnow/libvmaf-sys"
authors = ["Brandon Piña"]
include = ["**/*.rs","Cargo.toml","Cargo.lock","vmaf/libvmaf","vmaf/model","vmaf/LICENSE","*.ini","wrapper.h"]
readme = "readme.md"
keywords = ["vmaf","video"]
links = "vmaf"
```

I haven't touched the _sys crate in a while and I remember being able to step into the C source code from this other project so I didn't think very much of it. Somehow in the changes I had to make to get my library to build on windows I managed to break this!